# Открыть консоль из WPF приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, консоль

Здравствуйте! Задача: скомпилировать код из языка A в язык B, и выполнить его. В консоли все работает, пишу Gui. Идея такая: сначала видимо только окно, при нажатии на кнопку **run** появляется консоль, вся программа выполняется там, когда программа выполнилась, консоль исчезает. Файл `MainWindow.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("Kernel32")]
    public static extern void FreeConsole();


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Compile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string code = ACode.Text;
        string B = (new ARunner((new Ast(code)).children[0])).Exec();
        BCode.Text = B;
    }

    private void Run(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Compile(sender, e);..
        AllocConsole();
        BRunner runner = new BRunner(BCode.Text);
        runner.Run();
        Console.ReadLine();
        FreeConsole();
    }
}
```

`ACode` и `BCode` - textbox'ы.
`ARunner`, `BRunner` и `Ast`определены в соседнем проекте.

Нагуглил про `AllocConsole` и `FreeConsole` [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11600355/how-to-open-close-console-window-dynamically-from-a-wpf-application).

Консоль появляется, но вывода нет. Причем, если попытаться вывести что-то после `AllocConsole()`, оно тоже не появится.

Не могли бы вы помочь?

Comment: а что делает `BRunner` и что получаеться в резултате `runner.Run();`?

Comment: @Vardan Vardanyan, `BRunner` принимает строку с кодом и исполняет ее в методе `void Run()`. Весь ввод/вывод происходит через `Console`.

Comment: можете показать код `ARunner` и `BRunner` если да добавтье в вопрос

Comment: @Rennorb: А откуда класс `Console` магическим образом узнает, что вы аллоцировали какую-то консоль?

Comment: `В консоли все работает`. Если все работает в консоли, значит ваша консольная программа уже написана, если она написана, то почему ее просто не запустить из WPF и не передать ей нужные данные на обработку?

Comment: Оно могло случайно работать в какой-то из версий. В одной из старых версий [был хак](https://stackoverflow.com/a/718505/276994), который как бы работал. В VS 2017 он снова не работает. Если вы уж аллоцируете сами консоль, то и выводите в неё вручную, через WinAPI.

Comment: @sp7, да, действительно, если нужно только выполнить код, можно просто вызвать Process.Start. А если пытаться прикрутить самописный дебагер?

Comment: @VladD, я, конечно, догадываюсь, что плохо искал, но найти что-то вразумительное про использование WinAPI на C# мне не удалось. Все, что нашлось, было про С++. Не подскажете, где можно почитать?

Comment: @Rennorb: Почитать можно что угодно по теме P/Invoke, да хоть [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions). Но по вашей проблеме это не поможет. У WPF-приложений нету встроенной функциональности консоли, поэтому хитрые вызовы WinAPI не обязаны правильно работать. То, что оно случайно работало в какой-то версии — случайно удавшийся хак.

Comment: В SharpDevelop так же работают стандартные Console.Write и Console.WriteLine. Достаточно только AllocConsole.

Answer (score 1):

Вот рабочий пример вывода на консоль с использованием WinAPI из WPF-приложения:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace confromwpf
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
        const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
        const int STD_ERROR_HANDLE = -12;
        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern void AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern void FreeConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int h);

        [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool WriteConsole(
            IntPtr h,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string s,
            int l,
            ref int lw,
            IntPtr zero);

        public static IntPtr hcon = IntPtr.Zero;


        public Window1()
        {
            int wc=0;
            InitializeComponent();
            AllocConsole();
            hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            const string hello = "Hello world!\n---\n";
            WriteConsole(hcon, hello, hello.Length, ref wc, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
}
```